# Javascript Number increased over current date **and saved each increase**

Tags: javascript, time, increment

This has to be super easy, just couldn't find the solution for the past three hours:

I want to display a number (100) on my website that will be increased by the days past, problem is that the number goes back to the 100 when I reload the website, how do I make that number stay increased over time?

Here's the code:

```
    <script>
    var smyle = 11406;
    var happyclients = 1006;
    var hours = 4220;

        window.setInterval(
            function () {
                smyle = smyle + 2;
                document.getElementById("smiles").innerHTML = smyle;
            }, 2880);

        window.setInterval(
            function () {
                happyclients = happyclients + 4;
                document.getElementById("happy").innerHTML = happyclients;
            }, 28800000);

        window.setInterval(
            function () {
                hours = hours + 8
                document.getElementById("hoursspent").innerHTML = hours;
            }, 86400000);
    </script>
```

The HTML

```
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft">
                    <div class="feature-center">
                        <span class="icon">
                            <i class="ti-music"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="counter js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="" data-speed="4000" data-refresh-interval="50" id="smiles"></span>
                        <span class="counter-label">Smiles Created</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I am new to JS, previously tried with PHP but couldn't find the answer either, this is the closest I got.

So far I've gotten to this with your help, the idea of storing the data on the local database is quite clean and efficient, but I'm not being able to make it work yet (see changes at the bottom of the code)

I've read plenty of documentation about this and I think that the order is correct, but is it?

```
    <script>

    var smyle = 11000;
    var happyclients = 1006;
    var hours = 4220;

        window.setInterval(
            function () {
                smyle = smyle + 2;

                document.getElementById("smiles").innerHTML = smyle;
            }, 288);

        window.setInterval(
            function () {
                happyclients = happyclients + 4;
                document.getElementById("happy").innerHTML = happyclients;
            }, 288);

        window.setInterval(
            function () {
                hours = hours + 8
                document.getElementById("hoursspent").innerHTML = hours;
            }, 864);

        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        // Store
        localStorage.setItem("smyle");
        //Retrieve
        document.querySelector("smiles").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("smyle");
        } else {
            document.write(11404);
        }

    </script>
```

I didn't change anything in the HTML part yet, so the id is still id="smiles"

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to store this somewhere, which could be a cookie or more easily just store it in a database. You can say for each user how long they have spent, by updating your database every few seconds or minutes. Then all you would need to do is pull for that data and check where the data is.

Currently, your method requires the user to have the page open continuously, which will in fact restart it every time as the JavaScript will have no sense of previous time spent.

Answer (score 0):

you can save it in `localStorage` on client side.
here is the [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

if you want the same result for everyone you should do this on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the data in `localStorage` will definitely help:

```
localStorage.setItem(//takes an object);
```

For retrieval:

```
document.querySelector("...").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(//takes object key);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, what do you think about the changes? I've read the whole https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp page multiple times and cannot find the weak link